# Nand Image unpacking/extraction from NAND S34ML04G100 BGA and MK MCIMX6S5DVM10AC

Tags: imx6

Hello everyone in this community!

i have a coffee machine running on MCIMX6S5DVM10AC processor with nand S34ML04G100.
OS: WINCE 7
open telnet and ftp ports

through the programmer, I took an image from nand: [image.bin](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q0BUCbalDwvgbLmmEWwJ-0r9wqLuYnIW/view?usp=share_link)

(the image is working, I restored it to a new nand memory and the coffee machine started working.)

full log startup from console:  [full_log_startup.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iZT2SVfnVRIC4mLKaxn17Ev4q1z5QaVA/view?usp=share_link)

boot options: [boot_options.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wONSk-8-tSiN1N7sx3kPk2RwgIfZH8KT/view?usp=share_link)

Can anyone share a tip for extracting a disk image? I want to know the telnet password. This password is also the FTP password.

what I need it for: I have a VNC server for this machine, it will help reduce the time for their maintenance. Price changes, configuration changes, and so on.

If more information is needed, I will provide it. I will be glad to any advice.

Thank you all!

I could not understand what file system is in the partitions. There are probably some peculiarities when working with imx architecture.